# python checksum md5 with argv called from a main.py

Tags: python, exception, subprocess, md5, argv

Is reference with my code to check the md5 from two sources in my link:

[python saving output from a for iteration and subprocess for checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416724/python-saving-output-from-a-for-iteration-and-subprocess-for-checksum)

I achieve getting md5 respectively. (Any improvements are always welcome) here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import hashlib
import os
import sys
from sys import *
import subprocess

#script, path, path2 = argv

outfile = "md5_origen.txt"
outfile2 = "md5_destino.txt"
cmdargs = sys.argv
total = len(sys.argv) -1

#EJEMPLO PARA SACAR LOS ARGUMENTOS
################
#for a in cmdargs[1:]:
#       print  a
################        

def saca_sum_origen(y):
        #si cambia de directorio, que cambio de archivo para despues ser evaluado.
        if a != sys.argv[total]: 
                ck = "md5 %s/%s" % (a,y)
                p = subprocess.Popen(ck, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                (output, err) = p.communicate()
                with open(outfile,'a') as text_file:
                        text_file.write("%s" % output)
        else:
                ck = "md5 %s/%s" % (a,y)
                p = subprocess.Popen(ck, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                (output, err) = p.communicate()
                with open(outfile2,'a') as text_file:
                        text_file.write("%s" % output)

#obtenemos los argumentos
for a in cmdargs[1:]:
        #esto es que cada directorio enliste los files que tiene adentro
        for x in (file for file in os.listdir(a)):
                if not "~" in x:
                        #que obtenga su MD5
                        saca_sum_origen(x)
```

**Wondering how can I start building a menu from an other python script.**

My first approach is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from sys import *
import sys
import subprocess
import cksum_v2
borrar = os.system('clear')

opcion = True
    while opcion:
            print "Select an option: \n"
            print "1. Create a md5 report from source and target only"
            try:
                    opcion = int(raw_input(">_ "))
                    if opcion == 1:
                            print "Jot down your input folder"
                            origen  = raw_input()
                            print "Now your output folder"
                            destino = raw_input()
                            subprocess.call(["./cksum_v2.py", origen, destino])
                            borrar
                            print "Done!"
                            print "¿Want an other? y/n"
                            try:
                                    descicion = str(raw_input(">_ "))       
                                    if descicion == "y":
                                            opcion = True
                                    elif descicion == "n":
                                            print "BYE"
                                            opcion = False
                                    else:
                                            print "ADIOS!!!"
                                            opcion = False
                            except:
                                    borrar
                                    print "BYE"
                                    opcion = False

                    elif opcion >1 or opcion <4:
                            os.system('clear')
                            print "Under construction"
                            opcion = True
                    elif  opcion >5:
                            print "Doesnt exist that option, an other?"
                            opcion = True
            except:
                    print "DOnt get mad, BYE touchy!!"
                    opcion = False
```

Comment: There are some dirty snippets on my code. Sorry about them... learning in progress...

Comment: So what happens when you run it?  Do you get an error, or just not the output you expected?

Comment: Works good. But im certain if is the best way to call the script: "cksum_v2.py" from main.py. Note that cksum_v2.py needs two arguments.

Comment: Instead of calling cksum_v2.py as a subprocess, why not just import it and call the saca_sum_origen function directly?

Comment: I dont know how to put it down as it has two arguments ( maybe more ) Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to call `saca_sum_origen` with a source and a destination, and right now it just takes 1 argument for the source.  The function just needs to be modified to take those arguments:

(I simplified it a bit here)

```
def saca_sum_origen(source, dest):
    ck = "md5 %s" % source
    p = subprocess.Popen(ck, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    with open(dest,'a') as text_file:
    text_file.write(str(output))
```

Then just replace this line `subprocess.call(["./cksum_v2.py", origen, destino])` with `cksum_v2.saca_sum_origen(origen, destino)`

By the way, it looks like you're trying to make a "shortcut" for a function with this line `borrar = os.system('clear')`.  All this does is assigns the output of `os.system('clear')`, (which is nothing) to the variable `borrar`, and then when you're trying to "call" it within your menu code, it's actually not doing anything.  If you really want to create an "alias" function, you can make it a function: `def borrar: os.system('clear')`, and don't forget the parenthesis when you call it:  `borrar()`